# Words that have confusing meanings in a diplomatic notice

Tags: word-choice

Here is a sentence excerpted from a notice posted at the official website of the Consulate-General of China in Toronto on Nov 1, 2017 as follows "中国驻多伦多总领馆再次郑重提醒广大华侨华人和中国留学生注意防范电信诈骗。"

How do we differentiate 华侨 and 华人 and 中国留学生？Doesn't 华人 include 华侨 and 中国留学生？If 华人 means Canadians of Chinese blood, then is it the proper and legal business of the diplomatic office of China to handle matters in their connection?

Answer (score 3):

华侨； Chinese people who live in other countries but are still citizens of China.

华人（广义）: people of Chinese blood

华人（狭义）：Chinese people who become citizens of other countries

(e.g.  美籍华人)

Answer (score 1):

- 华人 means "Chinese people" regardless of nationality
- 中国留学生 means "Foreign Students who came from China"

**Edited:**

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1778/
>
> 华侨
>
> overseas Chinese; ethnic Chinese residing abroad, usu a citizen in the country of residence

**Note:** *Someone claims China and Taiwan citizens believe 華僑 only means "Chinese people who live in other countries but are still citizens of China," but many older generation immigrants, would still refer themselves as 華僑 regardless of nationality*

Comment: On the contrary, 华侨 are still citizens of China.

Comment: No, they are not citizens  of China once they became citizens of other countries, China does not recognize multiple citizenships

Comment: @TangHo, but according to both dictionaries and Baidu, "华侨亦被称作“海外华侨”，指尚未加入外籍的中国公民，但长期居于国外。" http://www.zdic.net/c/e/151/334934.htm ; https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8D%8E%E4%BE%A8/261731?fr=aladdin ;

Comment: I live in Canada, the people I know who call themselves 华侨 all have Canadian citizenship, may be they don't know what 华侨 meant then

Comment: It has nothing to do with China citizenship law. I understand maybe someone outside PRC/ROC use this term to address themselves. But this term has strict definition in both PRC and ROC. For PRC: http://www.gqb.gov.cn/node2/node3/node5/node9/userobject7ai1272.html, 《中华人民共和国归侨侨眷权益保护法 》第二条 归侨是指回国定居的华侨。华侨是指定居在国外的中国公民。 For ROC: http://law.moj.gov.tw/LawClass/LawAll.aspx?PCode=E0040019 華僑身分證明條例 第 3 條  本條例適用之對象，為僑居國外國民。

Comment: @TangHo So when you have problems like the fraud, you would turn to Canadian police rather than Chinese embassy for help, right? Obviously, the above office does not know what they should and can do in a foreign country.

Comment: @NanningYouth  "华人" in "华侨华人和中国留学生" just means "Chinese people",  for example, a visiting Chinese citizen is certainly a 华人. I as a Canadian citizen, is  加籍华人,  can still call myself a 华人.   Actually, anyone can turn to Canadian police for help as long as the crime happened in Canada. If you seek help from Chinese embassy because you can't speak English, the embassy would just ask the Canadian police to investigate the crime.

Answer (score 1):

華者﹒chinese 也, it's up to you to define it¹

僑者﹒寄也﹒客也﹒have a domicile out of "china" (taiwan or p.r.c.)

華僑 should be any chinese whom live in other countries for long time, or permanently. they may has nationality of their domicile, or multiple nationalities; or, they still have p.r.c. passport, or taiwan passport.

> 华侨； Chinese people who live in other countries but are still citizens of China

it's **false** info.

> 華僑華人和中國留學生

it should be interpreted as "華僑", "華人" & "中國留學生"; with underlying assumption that they're han chinese (漢族)

"中國留學生" are students studying in canada, with origins from p.r.c.

"華人" is referring to the groups of people that's staying in canada temporary. e.g. tourists, persons on business trip, officials on visit.

these types of people have their domiciles in taiwan, or p.r.c. no matter how long they stay in canada (from a few days to months), they will leave. so, technically they're not "華僑"

¹   if you treat "華" as "中華民族" (the chinese people), it's tricky to interpret tibetan, mongolian, uyghurs & manchurian. claiming they're "chinese" is . . . :(

have fun :)

Comment: You wrote: "華僑 should be any Chinese whom live in other countries for long time, or permanently. They may has nationality of their domicile, or multiple nationalities; or, they still have p.r.c. passport, or Taiwan passport." I as a Hong Kong born Chinese also thought it is what 華僑 meant. Now, Dan claims this term has strict definition in both PRC and ROC. Therefore, for China and Taiwan citizens , 華僑 should only mean  Chinese people who live in other countries but are still citizens of China.

Comment: such info is false :(

Comment: You meant Dan is wrong about  the term 華僑 has strict definition in both PRC and ROC? I wouldn't know because I don't live in China or Taiwan

Comment: How about a business person who stays in a foreign country longer than a few months like 2 or three years for a project, is he a 华人 or a 华侨? Why give special treatment to 中国留学生? Because they are funded by government? But there are many students on their own expense.

Comment: @tang ho, the info quoted by dan is false, well, i stated it in my answer. :)

Comment: @nannig youth, consider the domicile. such business person has a permanent home, relatives, friends in "china"; after the project, he'll return. so, he's "華人".

Comment: the rationale of single out "中國留學生" are: they're the largest groups of chinese in canada, secondly, errrr, some of them are members of the fraud syndicate; or, there're higher risk that students would join the syndicate for earning money. in fact,  "中國留學生" are the main target of such notice, "華僑" & "華人" were listed, just for the purpose of "remaining face" to the students.

Comment: CantoDict editor agree with your post, http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/1778/